# Updating JTable data via setDataVector function

Tags: java, swing, list, vector, jtable

I'm trying to update my JTable by reading in a csv file and calling setDataVector, but am having some trouble with the conversion between a List of String[]s (the result of reading in the CSV file)  and a Vector of Objects (required for the setDataVector method). My attempt is below:

```
 jbtLoad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 try {  
                     CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("csv.csv")); 
                     List myEntries = reader.readAll();//List is filled with String[]'s

                     Vector<Object> data = new Vector(myEntries);
                     data.remove(0);

                     Vector<Object> column_names = new Vector();
                     column_names.add(myEntries.get(0));

                     tableModel.setDataVector(data, column_names); //the error occurs here
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex) {
                 ex.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
        });
```

setDataVector is supposed to accept the following arguments: (Vector dataVector,Vector columnIdentifiers).

The trouble is I keep getting an error: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.util.Vector. Is there some easy function already out there that could fix this program? Or do I need to build something on my own?

I know vectors are depreciated, but given the limited scope of my program is (just a small homework assignment) I figure that it would just be easier use them.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: provide setDataVector API's implementations

Answer (score 1):

- data should be two dimensional array `Vector<Vector<Object>> data` instead of `Vector<Object> data`
- in this case you have to loop inside `util List myEntries` and to create a new `Vector<Object> row`
- use `AbstractTableModel` for underlaying array based on `util.List`,
- read [Oracle tutorial How to use Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), a few good code examples in SSCCE form is here